# Modifying source code in gem5 and rebuilding?

Tags: gem5

I need to modify source code in gem5.
For testing, I add a cprintf() statement in src/cpu/o3/fetch_impl.hh. Then using scons, I rebuild gem5. But, any change didn't happen. What did I miss?

Comment: On mailing list: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg17468.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't reproduce in gem5 d7d9bc240615625141cd6feddbadd392457e49eb (Tue Jan 21 18:03:44 2020).

After a full build with:

```
scons -j`nproc` build/ARM/gem5.opt
```

I modify the file `src/cpu/o3/fetch_impl.hh` by adding `#error` to the top, and then after re-running:

```
scons -j`nproc` build/ARM/gem5.opt
```

the build fails as expected, and so that file did get updated.

Try to reproduce what I did, and then provide further details.

You can also use the `scons --verbose` flag to see what GCC commands are being issued.

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10, scons 3.1.1.